# Cannot Import fbprophet in streamlit

Tags: python, miniconda, streamlit, facebook-prophet

Recently I have installed the `fbprophet` module for one of my Streamlit app. When I use `fbprophet` in any of the python project it works fine, but when I try to import `fbprophet` in my Streamlit app it throws this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fbprophet'
```

I tried to run the app in an conda environment and installed streamlit and `fbprophet` inside that environment and but it is still not working.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: what do you get when you run >>> print fbprophet.__version__ ?
does it recognizes the version you have installed ?

Comment: I get an answer `0.7.1`